# play framework 2.0 - how to enable the CRUD module

Tags: playframework, crud, playframework-2.0

I'm wondering how to enable the CRUD module in Play V2.0
I found this doc for V1.2.3:

```
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/crud
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no CRUD generation for now in Play 2.0

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/0g7YhdzA6Fs/xXSoW25X4ekJ

Comment: @TomTom: use forms (www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaForms) instead of CRUD you'll be satisfied.

Comment: Yes for sure. Thats the way to go to implement an admin section by myself. But it is no out-of-the-box admin section. I'm coming from Django and I'm a bit spoiled with the out-of-the-box admin functionality.

Comment: i like play 2 less and less

Answer (score 4):

You can try [my CRUD implementation](https://github.com/hakandilek/play2-crud) for Play2. It's not the one that you're used to with Django, but does the job with a little bit of effort.